# SMD Connector type?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to find the connector type (see links below) for some time with out success.

The pitch is 1.25mm.

Also the "Shrouded Header WR-WTB" is really similar but the "key" is not in the center.Also the pins are closer to the pcb in my connector.

http://imageshack.com/a/img534/2446/s66h.png

http://imageshack.com/a/img200/3314/6oj2.png

Comment: Possibly some [Molex](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoblade&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors) copy cat?

Comment: The "Shrouded Header WR-WTB" is really similar but the "key" is not in the center.Also the pins are closer to the pcb in my connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pitch of the connector is 1.25mm, then it might be [1734261-4](http://www.te.com/catalog/bin/TE.Connect?C=17259&M=PPROP&P=173437,302,2323&BML=10576,17560,17584,17579,17760&LG=1&PG=1&IDS=471553,471637,471650,471664,471678,471744,471772,721188,715534,471787,153869,721192,471566,153873,153886,153848,471758,153878,153882&N=1) from TE Connectivity. Please check the datasheet of the connector from the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The pitch is hard to measure with a big caliper.

Comment: I agree. :) However, please verify all the relevant dimensions from the datasheet with the component which you have on board.